# `[nosep]` not compacting items inside table as expected

Tags: tables, lists, itemize, enumitem

I want a much compact version (reduce line spacing between itemized items) of items inside table cells, so I used `[nosep]` for items. It reduced the spaces but still showing far from what I need. Any alternate way to compact more?

#### Code inside template:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption*{(i) Based on the type of battery RFID tags can be of three types:}
\small
  \begin{tabular}{ |c|p{2cm}|p{10cm}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Ser} &  \textbf{Item} & \Centering \textbf{Detail}
    \\ \hline
        1. & Active & \begin{itemize}[nosep]
                        \item Has its own transmitter and power source (Battery)
                        \item Transmits signal from the microchip circuit through the power obtained from the internal battery
                        \item High signal range
                        \item Larger in size
                        \item Expensive than passive
                        \item The batteries must be replaced
periodically
                     \end{itemize} \\ \hline
        2. & Passive & \begin{itemize}[nosep]
                        \item Operate without a separate external power source
                        \item Obtains operating power from the reader
                        \item Low signal range
                        \item Cheaper than active tags
                        \item Smaller in size
                     \end{itemize}  \\ \hline
        3. & Semi passive/ Battery Assisted Passive (BAP) & \begin{itemize}[nosep]
                        \item Has a small battery and is activated when in the presence of an RFID reader
            \item Communication method is same as the passive tag
                     \end{itemize}  \\ \hline
     \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
```

#### Output for template:

[image]

### Update - 1:

When I moved the code from template into new simple documentclass article, I found it compacts well. What can be the possible cause of the issue?

#### Code for scratch:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cite, changepage, calc,  enumitem, linegoal, datetime}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption*{(i) Based on the type of battery RFID tags can be of three types:}
\small
  \begin{tabular}{ |c|p{2cm}|p{10cm}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Ser} &  \textbf{Item} &  \textbf{Detail}
    \\ \hline
        1. & Active & \begin{itemize}
                        \item Has its own transmitter and power source (Battery)
                        \item Transmits signal from the microchip circuit through the power obtained from the internal battery
                        \item High signal range
                        \item Larger in size
                        \item Expensive than passive
                        \item The batteries must be replaced
periodically
                     \end{itemize} \\ \hline
        2. & Passive & \begin{itemize}[nosep]
                        \item Operate without a separate external power source
                        \item Obtains operating power from the reader
                        \item Low signal range
                        \item Cheaper than active tags
                        \item Smaller in size
                     \end{itemize}  \\ \hline
        3. & Semi passive/ Battery Assisted Passive (BAP) & \begin{itemize}[nosep]
                        \item Has a small battery and is activated when in the presence of an RFID reader
            \item Communication method is same as the passive tag
                     \end{itemize}  \\ \hline
     \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
  \end{document}
```

#### Output for scratch:

[image]

Comment: What spacing exactly do you want to reduce? Please also make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the packages that are relevant to the question.

Comment: I wanted to reduce spaces between lines for itemized items inside table cell. Interesting, when I moved the table into a small example of documentclass article, it compatcs well, but on my custom template it does not compact further. What could be the possible reason @leandriis?

Comment: @leandriis I have updated the post, could you guide where can be the possible issue?

Comment: As I already mentioned [in the comments to an earlier quite simlar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531746/how-to-enumerate-contents-inside-a-table-cell-in-latex/531749#comment1344522_531749) it is impossible to tell you why it does not work without seeing the actual code that you used to produce teh shown output.

Comment: Is there a reason for loading both `enumerate` and `enumitem`?

Comment: @Mico yes, I found `\usepackage{enumerate}` and `\usepackage{cite, changepage, calc,  enumitem, linegoal, datetime}` in my template. Is it problematic?

Comment: There can be no justification for loading both packages. `enumitem` is way more capable than `enumerate`; you figure out which one you should load.

Comment: @Mico I commented `\usepackage{enumerate}` but the problem still persistent. Moreover, when I added both in second MWE, it did not change line space between items. There might be some other issue. Although, there are many `\newcommand` in my template.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan - Please see the answer I just posted. It loads the `enumitem` package, but not the `enumerate` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest that you

- employ a `tabularx` environment, with the third column (of type `X`) set up to expand automatically to maximum possible width while allowing automatic line breaking; and
- use the machinery of the `enumitem` package to create a custom itemize-type list environment called `myitemize` -- feel free to come up with a snazzier name! -- which employs the `nosep` option and which embeds itself in a `minipage`, all done transparently "behind the scenes".

  (Because it uses the low-level macro `\hsize` macro, the `myitemize` environment should be used only in an `X` column. Of course, as always, *if you know exactly what you're doing* you may succeed in using `myitemize` in other circumstances as well. However, it's *not guaranteed* to work outside an `X`-type column in a `tabularx` environment.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
%% Ragged-right rather than full justification in narrow columns:
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

% Create a bespoke itemize-type list environment
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize]{label=\textbullet, nosep, left=0pt,
                    before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
                    after ={\end{minipage}} }

\usepackage{caption} % for "\caption*" macro
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip,
              justification=RaggedRight,
              singlelinecheck=false}

% Calculate width of second column:
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Battery Assisted}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less "cramped look
\caption*{(i) Based on the type of battery, RFID tags can be of three types:}
%\small  % not needed
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| c | P{\mylen} | L |}
    \hline
    Ser & Item & Detail \\ 
    \hline
    1. & Active & 
          \begin{myitemize}
          \item Has its own transmitter and power source (Battery)
          \item Transmits signal from the microchip circuit through the power obtained from the internal battery
          \item High signal range
          \item Larger in size
          \item Expensive than passive
          \item The batteries must be replaced periodically
          \end{myitemize} \\ 
    \hline
    2. & Passive
       & \begin{myitemize}
         \item Operate without a separate external power source
         \item Obtains operating power from the reader
         \item Low signal range
         \item Cheaper than active tags
         \item Smaller in size
         \end{myitemize}  \\ 
    \hline
    3. & Semi passive\slash Battery Assisted Passive (BAP) 
       & \begin{myitemize}
        \item Has a small battery and is activated when in the presence of an RFID reader
        \item Communication method is same as the passive tag
        \end{myitemize}  \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for clever defined `myitemize` :-)