# How to avoid table floating above the section text?

Tags: tables, spacing, sectioning, tabularx, enumitem

Following the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531990/200866) of Mico to bring both tables in single page by reducing space between items.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1.5in}

%% Ragged-right rather than full justification in narrow columns:
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

% Create a bespoke itemize-type list environment

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize]{label=\textbullet, nosep, left=0pt,
                    before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
                    after ={\end{minipage}} }

\usepackage{caption} % for "\caption*" macro
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip,
              justification=RaggedRight,
              singlelinecheck=false}

% Calculate width of second column:
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Battery Assisted}

\begin{document}
\section{Classification of RFID}
\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less "cramped look
\caption*{(i) Based on the type of battery, RFID tags can be of three types:}
%\small  % not needed
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| c | P{\mylen} | L |}
    \hline
    Ser & Item & Detail \\ 
    \hline
    1. & Active & 
          \begin{myitemize}
          \item Has its own transmitter and power source (Battery)
          \item Transmits signal from the microchip circuit through the power obtained from the internal battery
          \item High signal range
          \item Larger in size
          \item Expensive than passive
          \item The batteries must be replaced periodically
          \end{myitemize} \\ 
    \hline
    2. & Passive
       & \begin{myitemize}
         \item Operate without a separate external power source
         \item Obtains operating power from the reader
         \item Low signal range
         \item Cheaper than active tags
         \item Smaller in size
         \end{myitemize}  \\ 
    \hline
    3. & Semi passive\slash Battery Assisted Passive (BAP) 
       & \begin{myitemize}
        \item Has a small battery and is activated when in the presence of an RFID reader
        \item Communication method is same as the passive tag
        \end{myitemize}  \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less "cramped look
\caption*{(i) Based on the type of battery, RFID tags can be of three types:}
%\small  % not needed
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| c | P{\mylen} | L |}
    \hline
    Ser & Item & Detail \\ 
    \hline
    1. & Active & 
          \begin{myitemize}
          \item Has its own transmitter and power source (Battery)
          \item Transmits signal from the microchip circuit through the power obtained from the internal battery
          \item High signal range
          \item Larger in size
          \item Expensive than passive
          \item The batteries must be replaced periodically
          \end{myitemize} \\ 
    \hline
    2. & Passive
       & \begin{myitemize}
         \item Operate without a separate external power source
         \item Obtains operating power from the reader
         \item Low signal range
         \item Cheaper than active tags
         \item Smaller in size
         \end{myitemize}  \\ 
    \hline
    3. & Semi passive\slash Battery Assisted Passive (BAP) 
       & \begin{myitemize}
        \item Has a small battery and is activated when in the presence of an RFID reader
        \item Communication method is same as the passive tag
        \end{myitemize}  \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: enter code here]

That works like a charm. However, when I add section at the beginning of the `\begin{document}` the 1st table goes above the section title while leaving the 2nd table in next page even though it seems there are enough space to accommodate all.

### Added Section

```
...
\begin{document}
\section{Classification of RFID}
\begin{table}
...
```

### New Output

[image]

1. Large empty space at the bottom of the 1st page is looking odd to me.
2. Section title should be at the top.

**How can I deal with this situation?**

Comment: I am new to Latex. Seems working with table is a real tough job to me :(

Comment: Change both instances of `\begin{table}` to `\begin{table}[h!]`.

Comment: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/134144)  might be interesting.

Comment: you could remove the `table` environment and just use the `tabular` or `tabularx`. The _only_ reason to use `table` is to specify that the table can be moved.